# Downloading FairPlay Streaming Server SDK

Tags: sdk, fairplay

I'm trying to include DRM in my app and wanted to download the SDK from https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/

I'm logged in as the Team Agent in the Apple Developer Enterprise Program, but I get the error '403 Forbidden'. I checked the latest licence agreement; it's accepted.

Anybody experienced that error before?
Happy for any hint.

Answer (score 2):

The FairPlay Streaming SDK is only available in the Apple Developer Program and not in the Apple Developer Enterprise Program.